# libraries files failed to opening

Tags: php, file-upload

why 'config.php' & 'opendb.php' libraries files are failed to open. it shows:

Warning: include(library/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'library/config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give some code and directory structure otherwise we can help only very limited.

Assuming that you have the following directory structure:

```
library
 - config.php
index.php
```

And you have the code in the `index.php`

```
include "library/config.php";
```

That should just work fine. So either your directory structure is different, or your code is different.
The include path should be either a relative path (starting from the current directory)

```
include "relativepath/file.php";
```

Or it can be a an absolute path starting from the root directory (starting with "/")

```
include "/home/user/path/file.php";
```

You can use `../` to travel folders up in the directory structure if you need a file that is one folder above for example.

Answer (score 0):

try this.if your config file is in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\library\config.php this path

include_once('library/config.php');